# C++ Downloading a file to appdata

Tags: c++, file, download, appdata

I'm trying to download a file to

```
 char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA");
lpURLDownloadToFile URLDownloadToFile;
HMODULE hUrlmon = LoadLibrary("URLMON.DLL");
URLDownloadToFile = (lpURLDownloadToFile)GetProcAddress(hUrlmon, "URLDownloadToFileA");
URLDownloadToFile(0, "http://example.com/test.zip",appdata+"test.zip", 0, 0);
```

I don't have an error when I write the path manually,But ı got error when I try to use appdata+"test.zip"

How can I do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine `char*` pointers by adding them like so, you need to concatenate those strings. You might want to use `std:string` instead which support `operator+=`.

```
std::string appdata(getenv("APPDATA"));
appdata += "test.zip";

HMODULE hUrlmon = LoadLibrary("URLMON.DLL");
URLDownloadToFile = (lpURLDownloadToFile)GetProcAddress(hUrlmon, "URLDownloadToFileA");
URLDownloadToFile(0, "http://example.com/test.zip", appdata.c_str(), 0, 0);
```